# Добавить k элементов структуры в конец файла

Tags: c++

Программа должна добавить элементы структуры, вывести содержимое файла, а затем добавить элементы, количество которых вводится с клавиатуры (сами элементы структуры тоже вводятся вручную). Вот код, который у меня получился, он, почему-то, не добавляет элементы в конец.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct book
{
    std::string name;
    std::string author;
    int year;
    int CountOfPages;
};

int main() {
    book *mas;
    fstream f("f.dat", ios::out);
    int n;
    cout<<"N?";
    cin>>n;
    mas=new book[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"?";
        cin>>mas[i].name;
        cin>>mas[i].author;
        cin>>mas[i].year;
        cin>>mas[i].CountOfPages;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        f<<mas[i].name;f<<"\n";
        f<<mas[i].author;f<<"\n";
        f<<mas[i].year;f<<"\n";
        f<<mas[i].CountOfPages;f<<"\n";
    }
    f.close();
    
    book b;
    f.open("f.dat", ios::in);
    do
    {
        f>>b.name;
        f>>b.author;
        f>>b.year;
        f>>b.CountOfPages;
        
        if(f.eof())break;
        cout<<b.name<<" "<<b.author<<" "<<b.year<<" "<<b.CountOfPages<<"\n";
    } while (!f.eof());
    f.close();
    
    int k;
    cout<<"K?";
    cin>>k;
    
    book *temp;
    temp = new book[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        cout<<"?";
        cin>>temp[i].name;
        cin>>temp[i].author;
        cin>>temp[i].year;
        cin>>temp[i].CountOfPages;
    }
    
    f.open("f.dat", ios::ate);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        f<<temp[i].name;f<<"\n";
        f<<temp[i].author;f<<"\n";
        f<<temp[i].year;f<<"\n";
        f<<temp[i].CountOfPages;f<<"\n";
    }
    f.close();
    
    f.open("f.dat", ios::in);
    do
    {
        f>>b.name;
        f>>b.author;
        f>>b.year;
        f>>b.CountOfPages;
        
        if(f.eof())break;
        cout<<b.name<<" "<<b.author<<" "<<b.year<<" "<<b.CountOfPages<<"\n";
    } while (!f.eof());
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нужно пояснить, что файл не для перезаписывания, а дописывания. См. [`ios::app`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode)